# App crashes while tapping on sign in button, and trying to get fragment EditText value

Tags: java, android, android-studio

have some problem with sign in method.
I have activity that contain fragment container and 2 buttons(sign in and sign up).
In on create method of the activity i'm initialize fragments, and adding the login fragment to the container.

In method onClickSignButtons i have switch case func that should get pressed button id and do some think according to the button id.

But on click button app crashes.

There is the log from logcat:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewById(int)' on a null object reference
        at  com.enjoyapp.eventmanagement.Screens.Login.View.LoginActivity.onClickSignButtons(LoginActivity.java:45)
```

LoginActivity

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginModel {

private LoginPresenter presenter;
private Fragment EmailAndPasswordFragment, userDetailsFragment;
private Fragment selectedFragment = null;
UserSingleton userSingleton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    presenter = new LoginPresenter(this);

    EmailAndPasswordFragment = new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment();
    userDetailsFragment = new UserDetailsFragment();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment())
            .commit();
    selectedFragment = EmailAndPasswordFragment;

}


public void onClickSignButtons(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSignIn:
            if (selectedFragment == EmailAndPasswordFragment) {
                userSingleton.setmEmail(((EditText) EmailAndPasswordFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.etEmail)).getText().toString().trim());
                userSingleton.setmPassword(((EditText) EmailAndPasswordFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.etPassword)).getText().toString().trim());
                presenter.signIn(userSingleton.getmEmail(), userSingleton.getmPassword());
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment())
                        .commit();
                selectedFragment = EmailAndPasswordFragment;
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btnGetStarted:
            //TODO edd signup methos
            break;

    }
}
```

EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment

```
public class EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment extends Fragment {

private EditText etEmail, etPassword;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_email_and_password_fields, container, false);

    etEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
    etPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

    return view;
}

}
```

LoginActivity.xml (Button)

```
<Button 
android:id="@+id/btnSignIn" 
android:layout_width="200dp" 
android:layout_height="50dp" 
android:layout_marginBottom="48dp" 
android:background="@null" 
android:onClick="onClickSignButtons"
android:stateListAnimator="@null" 
android:text="@string/btn_sign_in" 
android:textColor="@color/white" 
app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent" 
app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />
```

Comment: where are you using this method ? onClickSignButtons(View view)?

Comment: @Umair in main activity

Comment: @Michael can you paste your login activity xml here because the click listener you added in your xml may have some problem

Comment: @vikaskumar <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="onClickSignButtons"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

Comment: @ShubhamJain tried , but not working

Answer (score 1):

From What i can see is you are initialising fragment and storing it in variable EmailAndPasswordFragment but while adding fragment to container you are again re initialising it.

Thats's why it is giving null pointer exception.

do this is your onCreate

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, EmailAndPasswordFragment)
        .commit();
```

Comment: Still got the same EXCEPTION

Answer (score 0):

the problem with your line

```
    EmailAndPasswordFragment = new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment();
```

because u are creating the Fragment object but assign it to the class name, not to the variable and then you are assigning to the variable `selectedFragment` which is assigned by class name.

**Solution** 
replace the line

```
EmailAndPasswordFragment = new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment();
```

with

```
EmailAndPasswordFragment ePF = new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment();
```

and line

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment())
            .commit();
    selectedFragment = EmailAndPasswordFragment;
```

with

```
getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, ePF)
                .commit();
        selectedFragment = ePF;
```

and replace the line 
 `if(selectedFragment == EmailAndPasswordFragment)` with `if(!(selectedFragment instanceof EmailAndPasswordFragment))`

Comment: I did exactly what you said, but still get the same error

Comment: please try to replace the line if (selectedFragment == EmailAndPasswordFragment) with  if(!(selectedFragment instanceof EmailAndPasswordFragment))

Comment: Still crashes with same exception

Answer (score 0):

```
EmailAndPasswordFragment = new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment();
```

This is first instance of  EmailAndPasswordFragment
and in add method your are passing new instance of EmailAndPasswordFragment

and inside onclick you are accessing value on first instance.

Comment: Ok now i changed the lines to :

private EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment ePF;
    private UserDetailsFragment uDF;
ePF = new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment();

        uDF = new UserDetailsFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, ePF)
                .commit();
        selectedFragment = ePF;

Answer (score 0):

Can you change your code as below: 
The reason for null pointer exception is that you are using another instance to call **findViewById()** which is not initialized yet and you are passing another to fragment manager.

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginModel {

private LoginPresenter presenter;
private Fragment emailAndPasswordFragment, userDetailsFragment;
private Fragment selectedFragment = null;
UserSingleton userSingleton;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    presenter = new LoginPresenter(this);

    emailAndPasswordFragment = new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment();
    userDetailsFragment = new UserDetailsFragment();

    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, emailAndPasswordFragment)
            .commit();
    selectedFragment = emailAndPasswordFragment;

}


public void onClickSignButtons(View view) {
    switch (view.getId()) {
        case R.id.btnSignIn:
            if (selectedFragment == emailAndPasswordFragment) {
                userSingleton.setmEmail(((EditText) emailAndPasswordFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.etEmail)).getText().toString().trim());
                userSingleton.setmPassword(((EditText) emailAndPasswordFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.etPassword)).getText().toString().trim());
                presenter.signIn(userSingleton.getmEmail(), userSingleton.getmPassword());
            } else {
                getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, emailAndPasswordFragment)
                        .commit();
                selectedFragment = emailAndPasswordFragment;
            }

            break;
        case R.id.btnGetStarted:
            //TODO edd signup methos
            break;

    }
}
```

also please don't use CAPS in naming conventions. always use camelCase. that will make you clear on what are you using.

Comment: Thanks for reply , i copy paste your code, but still have the same Exception

Comment: please do one thing paste your full code here including xml also for login activity. and can you assure me you have tried this after i have added a commet here.

Comment: Yes i tried after you added a comment. https://stackoverflow.com/a/58027725/10837992 this is a new code

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:
Ohhh god i'm sorry guys ,
I just forgot to initialize UserSingleton class.

just added to onCreate method next line:
userSingleton = UserSingleton.getInstance();

There is a new code with the xml

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements LoginModel {

    private LoginPresenter presenter;
    private Fragment emailAndPasswordFragment;
    private Fragment userDetailsFragment;
    private Fragment selectedFragment = null;
    UserSingleton userSingleton;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

        presenter = new LoginPresenter(this);

        emailAndPasswordFragment = new EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment();
        userDetailsFragment = new UserDetailsFragment();

        getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, emailAndPasswordFragment)
                .commit();
        selectedFragment = emailAndPasswordFragment;

    }


    public void onClickSignInAndUpButtons(View view) {
        switch (view.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnSignIn:
                if (selectedFragment == emailAndPasswordFragment) {
                    userSingleton.setmEmail(((EditText) emailAndPasswordFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.etEmail)).getText().toString().trim());
                    userSingleton.setmPassword(((EditText) emailAndPasswordFragment.getView().findViewById(R.id.etPassword)).getText().toString().trim());
                    presenter.signIn(userSingleton.getmEmail(), userSingleton.getmPassword());
                } else {
                    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fields_container, emailAndPasswordFragment)
                            .commit();
                    selectedFragment = emailAndPasswordFragment;
                }

                break;
            case R.id.btnGetStarted:
                //TODO edd signup methos
                break;

        }
    }
```

Login activity XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradien_color"
    tools:context=".Screens.Login.View.LoginActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/logoMain"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="52dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/logo_main"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:srcCompat="@drawable/logo_main" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fields_container"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/cvGetStarted"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/logoMain">

    </FrameLayout>

    <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cvGetStarted"
        android:layout_width="300dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:translationZ="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnSignIn"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.456"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
        card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnGetStarted"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/register_button_style"
            android:text="@string/btn_get_started"
            android:textColor="@color/white" />
    </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="48dp"
        android:background="@null"
        android:onClick="onClickSignInAndUpButtons"
        android:stateListAnimator="@null"
        android:text="@string/btn_sign_in"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.497"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />


</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Fragment class

```
public class EmailAndPasswordFieldsFragment extends Fragment {

    private EditText etEmail, etPassword;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_email_and_password_fields, container, false);

        etEmail = view.findViewById(R.id.etEmail);
        etPassword = view.findViewById(R.id.etPassword);

        return view;
    }

}
```

Fragment xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Screens.Login.View.UserDetailsFragment">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="350dp"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:translationZ="8dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etEmail"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/input_field_style"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/login_icon"
                android:drawableTint="@color/tint_and_text_color"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/hint_email"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
                android:textColorHint="@color/tint_and_text_color"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="250dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:translationZ="8dp"
            card_view:cardBackgroundColor="@android:color/transparent"
            card_view:cardCornerRadius="25dp"
            card_view:cardElevation="3dp">

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etPassword"
                android:layout_width="250dp"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:background="@drawable/input_field_style"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/password_icon"
                android:drawableTint="@color/tint_and_text_color"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="@string/hint_password"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:textColor="@color/main_text_color"
                android:textColorHint="@color/tint_and_text_color"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```